# .htaccess block for hostname "."

Tags: .htaccess

quick one for Apache gurus - 
how to block a hostname that is simply: .
-without blocking anything else.
Not sure how they managed to achieve this but it seems to be a bot that doesn't want to be identified. 
Latest IP is 204.45.209.208 uses various OS in user agent string.
cheers
rob

Comment: Can you clarify where that hostname is coming from?  A host header on a request, or the hostname of that 204.45.209.208 address?

Comment: Hi Shane - Yes, its the hostname of the address 204.45.209.208

Comment: wow. everything from the 209.xxx that I tried resolves to '.'

Answer (score 1):

You could block it with IP-tables.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 204.45.209.208 -j DROP
```

Comment: @Rothbert says that the *latest* IP is 204.45... so there are clearly more that have resolved to `.`, so iptables may not be a good solution.

Comment: @Iain @TiZon - that's correct, coming from a range of IPs. Wondered if there's a rewrite that would do the trick something like: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^.   ?

Comment: Can't he just block whole subnetwork in iptables?